# Convert linux ldapsearch to Windows dsquery

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, ldap, dsquery

I am converting a website fro being hosted on Linux and Apache to Windows and IIS. The pages are currently written in php but new functionality will be in something along the lines of C#.net


In the php files there is a popen command calling the ldapsearch command for linux and performing a query based on the users' id. What I need to do is switch this command over to dsquery, does anyone know of an easy way to convert between the two commands.


I have looked at Microsofts' documentation for dsquery but it seems lacking compared to ldapsearch. If anyone has a suggestion that may better fit this require I am open to the idea, but using dsquery or ldifde (or another built-in command) would be best.


Thank you for your help and replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP code should not have called ldapsearch.
instead: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php

.net code should not call dsquery.
instead: use native tools (not as easy to find online docs)
useful(?): http://www.youcanlearnseries.com/Programming%20Tips/CSharp/LDAPReader.aspx

Comment: Thank you, this information is quite valuable. I am pretty much fixing a broken product and then will be replacing it after it is not completely falling apart. I have marked your answer as the right one. Also, if it helps anyone else here is how I got the dsquery to work:
 dsquery user -d domain -u username -p password -samid uniqueID
Below Jim B using the filter argument that I didn't know about would also work to filter down by uid and would probably be more precise. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you were looking in the right place for the documentation?  Here is a link to the [dsquery command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732952%28WS.10%29.aspx).  the ldapsearch syntax should be very similar from a dsquery filter perspective.

off hte top of my head (meaning I didn't test this) to query for a user by uid:

```
dsquery * domainroot -filter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(uid='100'))" -attr samaccountname -limit 0
```